# Exceptions thrown by trigger in Financial Service Cloud and permissions issues

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein, managed-package

I have installed a managed package called Financial service cloud (Salesforce is the owner of that app) in my org when I'm trying to create new records on the custom objects which they have provided in this case some triggers are throwing errors.

> Error:FinServ.FinancialAccountRoleTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: FinServ.MoiExceptionWrapper.TriggerException: Something's not quite right. Try your action again, and if the issue continues, contact your administrator for help.

One more issue, there is pre-installed Einstein Analytics app in the managed package when I'm trying to open any it is throwing insufficient privileges error.

> Error: The asset cannot be displayed because you don't have sufficient permissions.

The profile which they have used is System Administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Einstein Analytics app will require the user be given the appropriate permissions - a permissionSet and some other items. It's well-documented in the Trailhead modules on learning Einstein Analytics.

As for the trigger error, that's something to raise with Salesforce, as managed package errors generally have to be handled by the ISV.

Comment: I have cleared the Einstein issue and for the trigger error raised a case with Salesforce. Thanks for the info David